# How can I get DataStax' Cassandra to authorize against nested groups in AD?

Tags: cassandra, active-directory, datastax-enterprise

My client has implemented an RBAC model in Active Directory, using roles and nested functional groups. It's all good.

My client now wants to assign functional groups to Cassandra roles, but the [DataStax documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/security/secLDAPScheme.html%20DataStax%20documentation) is somewhat lacking here, and our first impression was that nested groups were out of the question.

Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution is to use one of Windows Active Directory's [magic numbers](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5392.active-directory-ldap-syntax-filters.aspx). Here is an excerpt of the deployed `dse.yaml` file:

`ldap_options:
    group_search_base: OU=Groups,DC=myorg,DC=org
    group_search_type: directory_search
    group_search_filter: (member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:={0})
    group_name_attribute: cn`

The documentation doesn't clearly explain this, but it appears that `{0}` expands to the entire distinguished name (DN), which is needed for the nested member search given in `group_search_filter`.